# How can Google IAM be used to manage authentication and authorization for a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-security-oauth2

I'm looking into the possibilities of using Google IAM to manage users and roles for a Spring Boot app that we're going to use in our organization.

All material I have found so far on IAM is how to manage roles for access to the Google Cloud platform, and not to the applications running on an Google Cloud Compute / Kubernetes Engine.

Is it possible to manage users and roles for specific applications in IAM, and if so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it’s not possible to use IAM to manage the access of an application. According with its documentation [1] “.......Cloud IAM  lets you manage access control by defining who (identity) has what access (role) for which resource.”, so IAM allows you to control the access to your resources inside of your project but at GCP services layer not at application level .

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview